# xamarin.forms, How to change app top layout

Tags: ios, xamarin, mobile, layout, xamarin.forms

I need to do some change in my aplication top of the ios device...
The *Back* button is orange, but I need that it, and only it, be white...
But when I chaged the page title to orange, it changed together...

[image]

I used this line in 'AppDelegate' to it:

```
UINavigationBar.Appearance.SetTitleTextAttributes(
    new UITextAttributes() { TextColor = UIColor.Orange });
```

Besides that, My statusbar is white...I changed it to black using this in appDelegate:

```
if (statusBar.RespondsToSelector(new ObjCRuntime.Selector("setBackgroundColor:")))
        {
            statusBar.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
        }
```

I can do it black, But I need it's letters be white...I searched and I can't find a answer that works...please, if you can, help me
it's really important to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.

This will set Title Color to Orange:

```
UINavigationBar.Appearance.SetTitleTextAttributes(new UITextAttributes()
{
    TextColor = UIColor.Orange
});
```

This will set the BackButton Color to White:

```
UINavigationBar.Appearance.TintColor = UIColor.White;
```

2.

To change status bar appearance follow this link: [Change Status Bar Icon & Text Colors](https://montemagno.com/ios-tip-change-status-bar-icon-text-colors/)

Comment: I am using UINavigationBar.Appearance.TintColor = UIColor.White;
and it doesn't change the text color

Comment: Can you post your complete code in FinishedLaunching()

Comment: I now the problem now, friend. the problem is this

Comment: <Style TargetType="NavigationPage">
                <!--<Setter Property="BarTextColor" Value="{StaticResource laranjacolor}" />-->
            </Style>

Comment: in my app.xaml...I did it to set orange color to android...because I don't know how do that in Android project

Comment: The above xaml code should work for both iOS and Android.

Comment: yeah...but when I put it in app.xaml...the back button of ios get orange color as its title...

Comment: solution1 should work in iOS, and  in android try this in your recent post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46637596/changing-android-nav-bar-title-in-xamarin-forms-project/46639424#46639424

Answer (score 0):

Change the text can be done using Xamarin Forms code on the `ContentPage` you want to effect:

In C# code:

```
NavigationPage.SetBackButtonTitle (this, "Something Other Than Back");
```

In XAML:

```
<ContentPage NavigationPage.BackButtonTitle="Back">
```

To change only the back button color requires a custom renderer. Check out [this](https://theconfuzedsourcecode.wordpress.com/2017/03/02/creating-an-identical-custom-navigation-bar-back-button-in-xamarin-ios/) post for an example of controlling the back button properties on iOS.