# Changing android nav bar title in xamarin.forms project

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin, mobile

I try to change android nav bar title of my xamarin forms project

I can't do that im app.xaml because when i change the color in pcl it changes ios back button too, And I don't wanna it...then I have already tried:

```
<resources>
 <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
</style>

 <style name="MyTheme.ActionBarStyle" 
 parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
  <item 
name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" 
parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#f08080</item>
 </style>
```

I read that I need to put something in the manifest but I Didn't found how to do that...

no error and nothing change...

My 'MainActivity':

```
namespace neoFly_Montana.Droid
{

[Activity(Label = "neoFly_Montana", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = false, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    public static Context AppContext;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);

        //qrcode inicializa
        ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.Android.Platform.Init();

        //inicializa imageCircle
        ImageCircleRenderer.Init();

        //inicializa o mapa
        global::Xamarin.FormsMaps.Init(this, bundle);

        //shared Preferences
        App.Init(new AndroidUserPreferences());

        //Gerenciador de memória
        CachedImageRenderer.Init();

        //AndroidUserPreferences sharedPref = new AndroidUserPreferences();
        //var token = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token;
        //sharedPref.SetString("token", token); joyce descomentar

        LoadApplication(new App());
    }

    // Field, property, and method for Picture Picker
    public static readonly int PickImageId = 1000;

    public TaskCompletionSource<Stream> PickImageTaskCompletionSource { set; get; 
 }

    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent intent)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

        if (requestCode == PickImageId)
        {
            if ((resultCode == Result.Ok) && (intent != null))
            {
                Android.Net.Uri uri = intent.Data;
                Stream stream = ContentResolver.OpenInputStream(uri);

                // Set the Stream as the completion of the Task
                PickImageTaskCompletionSource.SetResult(stream);
            }
            else
            {
                PickImageTaskCompletionSource.SetResult(null);
            }
        }
    }

    //qrcode permission
    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        global::ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.Android.PermissionsHandler.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }    

}
}
```

If I change the theme to MyTheme this exception ocures:

> Unhandled Exception: Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to change?  Do you want to change only the title text color, but not the other text colors?  It would be really helpful if you stated that in your question, instead of making us guess.

Comment: only the title text color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I try to change android nav bar title of my xamarin forms project

As [Rendy Del Rosario said](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/37657/how-to-change-the-nav-bar-background-color-on-android), setting a theme to `MainActivity` defined in a `Styles.xml` inside Android `Resources/values`instead of put this style in the manifest.

1. **Defined in a `Styles.xml` inside Android `Resources/values`**

[image]

Your `Styles.xml` :

```
<resources>
     <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
         <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
     </style>

     <style name="MyTheme.ActionBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
         <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
     </style>

     <style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
         <item name="android:textColor">#f08080</item>
     </style>
</resources>
```

2. **Set activity theme**

Add your custom style :

```
[Activity (Label = "WorkingWithNavigation.Droid", Theme = "@style/MyTheme",
    Icon = "@drawable/icon", 
    MainLauncher = true, 
    ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
{
    ...
}
```

Effect :

[Use theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4j3u.png), [No theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjpZ7.png).

**EDIT :**

> Unhandled Exception: Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

I read your `MainActivity` code, this error occurs because the activity you are trying to apply the dialog theme to is extending `AppCompatActivity` which **requires the `AppCompat` theme to be applied**. To solve this problem and implement your feature I found another solution and it works fine on my side.

Since you are using toolbar in your `MainActivity` :

```
ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
```

**The nav bar title in Android is `Toolbar`, so you just need to change the toolbar title color.**

**1.Using the default theme when you create a `Xamarin.Android` project :**

`Resources/values/Styles.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>

  <style name="ToolbarTheme" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#ff0000</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
  </style>

  <style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">#2196F3</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1976D2</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>
  </style>

  <style name="AppCompatDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

**2.Add a `ToolbarTheme` to your `Toolbar` :**

**Define a `ToolbarTheme`**, place it in `Resources/values/Styles.xml` file, you could see it in the above code, I write here again :

```
 <style name="ToolbarTheme" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#ff0000</item>
 </style>
```

The `android:textColorPrimary` is the nav bar title color, replace it with the color you want to change.

Find your `Toolbar.axml` file :

[image]

Modify your `Toolbar` theme to :

```
android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
```

Complete `Toolbar.axml` code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Effect :

When I change the toolbar title color to red ：

```
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">#ff0000</item>
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand...The first code that you posted about style I know I should to put it in the style.xml inside the resources folder...But the part when you said "Add your custom style" I don't know where I put this code

Comment: @Joyce de Lanna, put it in your `MainActivity` as an `Attribute`.

Comment: @Joyce de Lanna, I have update my answer, please check it.

Comment: Thanks, if I put it in the mainActivity does the others activities (pages of pcl) receive it too?

Comment: Unhandled Exception:

Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Comment: @Joyce de Lanna, please post your `MainActivity` code and its theme, something like my second code.

Comment: @Joyce de Lanna, I have update my answer, please check it.